# Bifrost config entries

Tags: bifrost

When issuer_public_key and signer_secret_key are used?

It seems that both values are ignored. I accidently put wrong values in issuer_public_key and signer_secret_key but everything is working fine for a couple of days now and now I noticed.

This is what I provide in bifrost.cfg:

```
issuer_public_key = "GATIJXESQLVCNWKQ3D6N6RMKTTEZARGMPKY4IGZD2CBJUEEVX3RTPH6K"
signer_secret_key = "somesecretkey"
token_asset_code = "DEMO"
needs_authorize = false
horizon = "http://stellarhorizon:8000"
network_passphrase = "Test SDF Network ; September 2015"
```

This is what I have in params of bifrost-js-sdk:

```
params = {
        network: 'test',
        horizonURL: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        bifrostURL: 'http://someurl:8800',
        assetCode: 'DEMO',
        price: '1',
        issuingPublicKey: 'GAQO2FENXXVMNSHTP2Q4GFTSOAPEWHVF743ZRZLJETNEDCCNJNHG4ZUS',
        preSaleMode: false,
    },
```

As you can see, both public keys are different and in stellarterm I can see that really the issuer of the params is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the bifrost-js-sdk a [trustline](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#trustlines) is set up for the asset of the issuing account on the *receiving* side. Without that trustline in place the `BTC/ETH` assets can not be transferred as the transaction would fail. Same for the later order of the `DEMO` token. Therefore the Bifrost *server* side [watches](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/bifrost/stellar/account_configurator.go#L121) the receiving account for the trustline set.

The `signer_secret_key` points to the account that holds the asset. It should be the issuing account when `AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED` is set.